# Text in Atom editor randomly mangles after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: 16.04, atom

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, I've been having a strange issue with my Atom editor.

As I scroll through a text file, or click around the editor, random sets of lines will get mangled.  It's not permanent, if I click somewhere again or scroll, those lines get rendered correctly but then a different set of lines get mangled instead.  Example here:

[image: Mangled text in Atom editor]

I haven't seen this happen in any other program as far as I can tell.

Comment: It also (randomly) becomes unresponsive. It also halted the entire system twice after running it (atom) from within a python virtual environment with the command `atom .`

Comment: @Denis There is an issue for this on Atom's GitHub repository at https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/11300, and it looks like there is no solution yet.